# Use a sde.st_geometry function in a PL/SQL trigger

Tags: oracle-dbms, function, st-geometry, trigger, plsql

I have a PL/SQL trigger:

```
1    create or replace trigger "projects_to_meas_trig" before update of asset_id 
2    on projects
3    
4    for each row
5    declare
6        v_length number;
7    begin
8        if :new.asset_class = 3 then
9            select sde.st_length(shape)
10            into v_length
11            from user1.roads
12            where  road_id = :new.asset_id;
13    
14            :new.to_meas := v_length;
15        end if;
16    end;
```

At `line #9`, when I try to use the `st_length` function, I get this error:

```
Error(4): PLS-00707: unsupported construct or internal error [2603]
```

Why can't I use the st_geometry function in a PL/SQL trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to "fully qualify the package":

```
select sde.st_geometry_operators.st_length_f(shape)  --<-- Don't forget the _f at the end
```

Interestingly, just adding `.st_geometry` also seems to work for `st_length()`. I discovered this by accident:

```
 select sde.st_geometry.st_length(shape)
```

From the [documentation](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010459) ([cached](https://web.archive.org/web/20160908020203/https://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010459)):

> **How To: Leverage st_geometry operators in Oracle's PL/SQL**
>
> Because the st_geometry functions are exposed as database operators,
> and typically consumed by way of SQL statements, leveraging the
> st_geometry functionality with PL/SQL requires referencing the
> underlying functions by fully qualifying their appropriate package and
> function name.
>
> Procedure:
>
> For example, to leverage the sde st_astext operator in PL/SQL, the
> call must reference the fully qualified package where the function
> resides. The following line of code demonstrates setting a local
> variable of type CLOB to the output of the st_astext function.
>
> Code:
>
> local_geometry_wkt :=
> sde.st_geometry_operators.st_astext_f(in_st_geom_feature);
>
> All geometry operators, such as st_astext, st_centroid,
> st_numgeometries, etc. reside in the st_geometry_operators package.
> All relational operators, such as st_intersects, st_within,
> st_contains, etc. reside in the st_relation_operators package.
>
> Note: When referencing any st_* operator as a function, remember to
> include the _f clause after its name to reference the appropriate
> function in the package body.

Related:

- Here's a [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVVDs.png) of what the package looks like in an SQL client.
- [Functions exposed as database operators — More succinct function calls in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905445/functions-exposed-as-database-operators-more-succinct-function-calls-in-pl-sql)